# VB.Net: Dynamicly created MonthCalendar does not fire LostFocus or GotFocus

Tags: vb.net, monthcalendar, lostfocus

I've created a form that has a tabbed control that gets users controls added to each tab dynamically and a StatusStrip at the bottom of the form.  When the app starts, the user controls are loaded in the tabs based on security with at least 1 tab being loaded.  On the StatusStrip, two ToolStripComboBoxes, 2 ToolStripButtons, 1 ToolStripLabel, and 1 ToolStripStatusLabel.  Everything loads fine and works.

I've been taksed to have a MonthCalendar popup when the user presses one of the two buttons.  Here's the code I use to do this:

```
If IsNothing(theCal) Then
    theCal = New MonthCalendar
    AddHandler theCal.DateSelected, AddressOf theCalDateSelected
    AddHandler theCal.LostFocus, AddressOf theCalLostFocus
    AddHandler theCal.GotFocus, AddressOf theCalLostFocus
    theCal.Parent = Me
    theCal.Top = StatusStripMain.Top - theCal.Height
    theCal.Left = ComboBoxAvailableLegDay.Bounds.X
    theCal.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom + AnchorStyles.Left
    theCal.Show()
    theCal.BringToFront()
    theCal.Focus()
Else
    Me.Controls.Remove(theCal)
    theCal = Nothing
End If
```

theCal is defined as Protected at the top of the form's class.  So, pressing the button will create the MonthCalendar and position it correctly if it doesn't exists and if it does exists, then it is removed.  This works with no problems.

My problem is that theCal never fires GotFocus or LostFocus.  I've got the procedure theCalLostFocus defined as follows and it never thows the exception.  I can put a breakpoint at the throw and the code never makes it to that point.

```
Private Sub theCalLostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub
```

Clicking a date on theCal will call theCalDateSelected procedure, but clicking any other area of the form does not fire theCalLostFocus.  Since the user may want to not select a date and I don't want to force them to have to press the button to remove theCal, I'd like to be able to remove theCal when it loses focus.  Anyone have any idea why this is happening and anyone got a solution?

Thanks.
-NCGrimbo

Answer (score 1):

i'm not that surprised that the focus event won't fire, because you add the handler *before* inserting it in the visual tree. try adding the handler after the call to show(). or maybe in the loaded event handler.  Note that since you request the focus, your focus event handler will be called every time.

Rq : as it is written, your code has memory leak since you do not remove the event handler when you clear theCal, so since a reference is kept to theCal, neither theCal nor the event handler get cleared and this lead to memory leak (cyclical reference).

Comment: I moved the AddHandler statements to the line after theCal.Show() and saw no change in behavior.  (And I added the removal of the event handlers per your note.)

Comment: I just noticed that the signature of your (Got/Lost)focus event handler is not right. It should be that of a routed event : (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

Comment: When I change the call to RoutedEventArgs, I get an error: type 'RoutedEventArgs' not defined.

Comment: strange... you don't have Presentation core in your references ?? 1) write System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs 2) if it still doesn't work, add PresentationCore to your references (project/references)